# Unsafe areas behind notches in the screen IOS 14 changes

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen, ios14, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Cordova IOS app shows white screen. I am using **xcode Version 12.0.**
Cordova IOS platform version is 6.1.0. (or 6.1.1) Cordova version is 10.0.0.
I am doing all changes for IOs14. for iPhone XR devices I am using meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,  width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
```

but still after first launch I am seeing white space below to notch area. Below are the plugin details and preferences in config.xml file.

```
Cordova 10
Cordova-ios: 6.1.1
**@globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr 1.1.0 "Cordova WKWebView File XHR Plugin"**
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.9 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.2.0 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ0Y8.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't include the height in your viewport, try

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

Comment: Tried but not worked for me, It has something with WKWebView
Viewport not able to take full device height at First load.
It load properly if I reload app.

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover'>
```

Make sure you have the safe area css like:

```
padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
margin-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom);
margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
```

You'll have to look into [VisualViewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport) 
to keep the bottom menu at the bottom.

Basically you force the full height, of the viewport div.

```
//not tested
window.visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', function () {
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height = window.innerHeight;
});
```

Especially if your app has orientation changes.